# Feature selection for a dataset using R

Tags: r, feature-selection

I have a dataset of dimension 1722x1226. Out of 1226 attributes only 3 attributes have variance (i.e. a near-zero variance score) greater than 0.12. Does this mean that all other attributes or variables are duplicates?

Should I only use those 3 attributes (those with variance > 0.12) to build my model?

Is there any better way to do feature selection?

Comment: Could you let us know which modeling technique you plan to use?  How sparse are the columns?

Comment: I am planning to use SVM.  can you please tell what do u mean by sparse of column?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Variance is a relative measure. If we look at the height of humans, the variance is very large if we measure in millimeters, and very small if we measure in kilometers. What are the units of your data? Could you scale your columns (or would that not make sense)? Are they all numeric? How many distinct values are there?

Comment: Overall, this question seems like a better fit for datascience.stackexchange - it is not a programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Does this mean that all other attributes or variables are duplicates?**

If an attribute has no variance that doesn't mean it's a duplicate, it means it's a constant. You indicated that most of them have *some* variance, but very little. So they are not strictly constant, but with little variance they are unlikely to be very predictive.

**2. Should I use only those 3 attributes (those with variance > 0.12) to build my model?**

Most likely, yes. However you have to consider the specifics of your subject matter -- what the dependent and independant variables are, as well as how the variables are coded to make a well-informed decision on which to include.

Moreover, it may be wise to test multiple specifications, compare cross-validation performance and keep an eye out for overwriting when you include more than your top 3.

**3. Is there any better way to do feature selection?**

There are lots of more sophisticated analyses that you can perform in addition to what you're already doing.  It's a pretty broad topic, so I'll direct you [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) to give you a resource that mentions some of them.

Keep in mind that in addition to feature *selection* you may also benefit from feature *engineering*. I'm sure that information from some of those 1,200 variables can be engineered into a smaller number of more predictive variables with higher variance.

Also, bear in mind even that if all 1,226 of your columns had high variance, you still shouldn't include all of them because your model would suffer from few degrees of freedom. You want the ratio of observations (rows) to predictors (variables) to be high.